# Adding columns to a 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Any desired `array` entered by the user , code look for every column , if any element in any column is equal to number `y`.Then the code should add a `new column of zeros`  in front of it.

> Code

```
#include <pch.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int y, rows, columns;
std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
std::cin >> rows;
std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
std::cin >> columns;
std::cout << "Enter a number Y: ";
std::cin >> y;

//-----------------------Generating 2-D array---------------------------------------------------------
int **array = new int*[2 * rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    array[i] = new int[columns];
//------------------------Generating bool--------------------------------------------------------------
bool *arrx = new bool[columns];
//-----------------------Input Array Elements---------------------------------------------------------
std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        std::cin >> array[i][j];
//--------------------Loop for the array output--------------------------------------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
//-------------------Loop for finding columns with even numbers----------------------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    arrx[i] = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        if (array[j][i] == y) {
            arrx[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
std::cout << "\n";
//--------------------Loop for addition of new columns infront of even numbers--------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    if (arrx[i]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            std::cout << 0 << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Here this code adds only rows to the `array` while I need to add `columns` . I have tried changing `array[i][j]` to `array[j][i]` but in vain.

Comment: any particular reason why you do not use `std::vector` ?

Comment: Because this is the last manual task , of adding and removing elements in our course . The next topic we are going to start is `std::vector`

Comment: please add such requirements to the question. Homework assignments often come with rather strange constraints, eg in real life no sane c++ coder would use manually allocated arrays for that task

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    if (arrx[i]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            std::cout << 0 << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        if (arrx[j]) {
           std::cout << 0 << " ";
         }
    }
}
```

This prints a zero after every element whose column value is marked. What you were trying to do is print to standard output column by column which is not how it works.

Also I urge you to consider using a std::vector instead of plain pointers to avoid errors like here where you have forgotten to deallocate your memory.

Comment: And should I change all the `arrx[i]` to `arrx[j]` ?